# AWS Amplify Cognito | Missing region in config after I refresh page

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building a web app in Angular using AWS as my backend, and got Cognito running, that I've set up via Amplify.

After I login to my web app in my browser on my localhost, everything runs perfect.

The problem is, as I work on my app, every time I make a change and the browser refreshes, I get the error:

```
ConfigError: Missing region in config
```

Since I used Amplify to set it up, I don't know where to set my region and why this keeps happening.

I use authguard to protect my pages, so only auth users are allowed to see all content but the login site.

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
try {
  let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  console.log('Yes, Im authenticated', user);
  return true;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Not authenticated ', e);
  this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
  }
 }
}
```

I'm a bit over my head here and have lost overview of what is what after working on this problem for so long, so if I need to provide some more code or explanation, I will be happy to do so.

Full console error:

```
ConfigError: Missing region in config
at Request.VALIDATE_REGION (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:210527:45)
at Request.callListeners (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:215956:20)
at callNextListener (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:215946:12)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:210521:9
at finish (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:206617:7)
at Config.getCredentials (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:206662:7)
at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:210516:26)
at Request.callListeners (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:215952:18)
at Request.emit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:215928:10)
at Request.emit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:214552:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I used the APP_INITIALIZER to get my regions in *before* the component was loaded, to fix this issue.

In my app module on providers I added to following:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
  multi: true
}
```

I then added a ts file in /app with the following:

```
import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';


export function startupServiceFactory() {
  return () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
      AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
      AWS.config.credentials = Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials);
      resolve();
    });
  };
}
```

Link to tutorial:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-app-initializer-token-to-hook-into